# Is the solution to the heat equation always $C^k$, no matter what the boundary condition is?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain (can be smooth if necessary). Consider the heat equation
$$u_t - \Delta u = 0$$
$$u(0) = u_0$$
$$\text{some Robin boundary condition (B) for $u$}$$
We know that $u$ lies in some Bochner space, and the first equation holds a.e.

My question is, is the solution of the heat equation always in $C^2(\Omega)$ (for fixed time), no matter what the boundary condition (B) is? I am asking for $C^2$ only on $\Omega$, not its closure so I can imagine it may be true.

Comment: All but a finite number of eigenvalues of $-\Delta$ will be positive, which means that the time evolution will put the solution in the domain of all positive powers of the operator $-\Delta$.

Comment: Don't the eigenvalues depend on the boundary condition? do you have any reference for this? thanks

Comment: Yes, of course the spectrum depends on the boundary condition. The Robin conditions that lead to well-posed operators I believe give you semibounded operators, which is why I stated "all but a finite number of eigenvalues..." The Schauder Approach chapter (6?) in Gilbarg and Trudinger has material dealing with this. Start by checking there.